# verbatim and figure side by side

Tags: floats, pdftex, positioning

I am trying to place an image beside a verbatim:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{columns}
  \begin{column}
    \begin{verbatim}
    2       0.0035768583
    2.67    0.0040359121
    4       0.0044441355
    6       0.0051378855 
    8       0.0057262546
    10      0.0062415249
    \end{verbatim}
  \end{column}
  \begin{column}
    \begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=.2]{example-image-golden}
  \caption{Gilbert Damping}
\end{figure}
  \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{document}
```

And the result is thie:  But I want them side-by-side. How can I achieve that?
[image: This is what I am ended with]

Comment: how are you defining the `columns` environment?

Comment: Please provide a MWE.

Comment: I guess columns is not available in article; i was carried away by beamer.

Comment: @SibaMishra: What do you think about the tex code shown?

Comment: @BaRud. Let me try.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the desired effect being side by side, may I infer that the `verbatim` content is also associated with the `figure`?  If so, one can use a `verbbox`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,verbatimbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbbox}[\small]
2       0.0035768583
2.67    0.0040359121
4       0.0044441355
6       0.0051378855 
8       0.0057262546
10      0.0062415249
\end{verbbox}
    \begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
  \theverbbox\qquad
  \includegraphics[scale=.3]{example-image-golden}
  \caption{Gilbert Damping}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If vertical centering is required, one can use the old `$\vcenter{\hbox{...}}$` method

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,verbatimbox,caption,stackengine}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbbox}[\small]
2       0.0035768583
2.67    0.0040359121
4       0.0044441355
6       0.0051378855 
8       0.0057262546
10      0.0062415249
\end{verbbox}
\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
  $\vcenter{\hbox{\theverbbox}}$\qquad
  $\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[scale=.2]{example-image-golden}}}$
  \caption{Gilbert Damping}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternately, there is the `\raisebox` approach:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,verbatimbox,caption,stackengine}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbbox}[\small]
2       0.0035768583
2.67    0.0040359121
4       0.0044441355
6       0.0051378855 
8       0.0057262546
10      0.0062415249
\end{verbbox}
\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
  \raisebox{-.5\ht\savedverbbox}{\theverbbox}\qquad
  \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[scale=.2]{example-image-golden}}
  \caption{Gilbert Damping}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

to achieve the same output.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot. Its working almost perfectly. Only problem is verbbox and figure is (horizontal) aligned to the bottom. Is it possible to make them center aligned?

Comment: @BaRud See my edit for a resolution.

Answer (score 7):

I suggest to put two minipages side by side, and to remove the `figure` environment. To add a caption without the `figure` environment use `\captionof{figure}{...}` provided by the package `caption` or `capt-of`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
  \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
    \begin{verbatim}
    2       0.0035768583
    2.67    0.0040359121
    4       0.0044441355
    6       0.0051378855 
    8       0.0057262546
    10      0.0062415249
    \end{verbatim}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-golden}\\
    \captionof{figure}{Gilbert Damping}
  \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Should probably specify that the caption package is what allows a caption outside of the figure environment.

Comment: @ScottSeidman Good suggestion, I've added a note.

Answer (score 1):

In a `beamer` presentation there is no need to specify that an image is a “figure” with a number, because you'll never reference it.

You need no `verbatim` either.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
  \column[t]{.4\textwidth}
  \vspace*{0pt}

  \ttfamily
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{\qquad}l@{}}
  2     &  0.0035768583 \\
  2.67  &  0.0040359121 \\
  4     &  0.0044441355 \\
  6     &  0.0051378855 \\
  8     &  0.0057262546 \\
  10    &  0.0062415249 \\
  \end{tabular}
  \column[t]{.6\textwidth}
  \vspace*{0pt}

  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.8\columnwidth]{example-image-golden}

  \bigskip

  Gilbert Damping
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]